# Ionic text to speech not canceling on ios device

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, text-to-speech, ionic-native

I'm trying to get the following code to work:

```
import { TextToSpeech } from '@ionic-native/text-to-speech/ngx';

constructor(
        private tts: TextToSpeech
    ) {}

ttsActive: boolean;

public textToSpeech(text) {
        if (this.ttsActive) {
            this.tts.stop();
        }
        this.ttsActive = true;
        this.tts.speak({text, rate: 1.5})
            .then(() => this.ttsActive = false)
            .catch((reason: any) => console.log(reason));
    }
```

It is working perfectly fine on an emulator, but when running it on a real device, tts is not canceling.

Is there any solution to this? I've seen solutions to call tts with an empty string, but this is also only working on an emulator...